# How to add subitem totals to get groupitem total in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, view

I am working on a trial balance page where I want am displaying totals of subgroup items. I want to display a group total. However, I am using {{ }} in the views to display the totals which are coming from the controller

```
@foreach($sage_paylater_staging as $sg)
 @if( $sg->credit_code == $ledgers->id && $sg->credit_code != '')
    {{ number_format($sg->amount, 2) }}
@endif
@endforeach
```

This is a code for the subitem total. I want to add the various subitems i.e the amount in the `{{ }}` and display a total in my group. How could I achieve this?

I have searched numerous websites but there is no way in which I could add the values in the `{{ }}` in the view. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You have to append that field to every item in the logic, before passing it to the view.. you can do it using methods map() or transform() on collections..

Comment: I have tried using the map() method, but it does not give the intended result. It does not pick the intended entries. It just picks the whole column and creates a sum, while what I want is individual columns, and then sum different entities

Comment: Sum the value inside a `foreach` & `if` and store it on variable. Here, you can't use `{{ }}` blade annotation. You have to use `@php` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
@php $total = 0; @endphp
@foreach($sage_paylater_staging as $sg)
    @if( $sg->credit_code == $ledgers->id && $sg->credit_code != '')
        @php $total += $sg->amount; @endphp
        {{ number_format($sg->amount, 2) }}
    @endif
@endforeach
{{number_format($total, 2)}}
```

But ideally you'd do that logic in your controller and pass the total as a var to the view.